# Spark SQL filtering according to a field in the most nested object

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON I load with Spark. I want to filter according to a field in the most nested object.
Here the schema of my JSON:

```
root
 |-- deezerUrl: string (nullable = true)
 |-- homeCities: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- homeCountries: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- labelCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- officialLanguage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- spotifyUrl: string (nullable = true)
 |-- visits: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- number: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- shows: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- project: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- theater: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- year: long (nullable = true)
```

With `filter(array_contains(df("visits.year"), 2004))` I found I can filter according to the field "year" which is a nested field, but I don't see how I can filter according to `city` for example (in the most nested object).

Here my code:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("Artist BDD")
    .getOrCreate()

  val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("result.json").toDF
  
  df.filter(array_contains(df("visits.year"), 2004)).show
}
```

Here a subset of my data:

```
json[
  {
    "name": "Zoot and The Roots",
    "officialLanguage": "EN",
    "labelCode": "GBR",
    "homeCountries": [
      "Royaume-Uni"
    ],
    "homeCities": [
      "York"
    ],
    "visits": [
      {
        "number": 9,
        "year": 1987,
        "shows": [
          {
            "date": "566089200",
            "city": "La Cité"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Border Crossing",
    "officialLanguage": "EN",
    "labelCode": "GBR",
    "homeCountries": [
      "Royaume-Uni"
    ],
    "homeCities": [
      "Londres"
    ],
    "deezerUrl": "https://www.deezer.com/fr/album/86869",
    "spotifyUrl": "https://open.spotify.com/album/2bDFUw8eB0OAIMigH77VVf",
    "visits": [
      {
        "number": 26,
        "year": 2004,
        "shows": [
          {
            "date": "1102114800",
            "city": "Parc des Expositions - Hall 5"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thank for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exploding it ?

```
df.filter(array_contains(explode(col("visits.shows")), "Paris")).show()
```

[Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

Comment: Yes I tried, but this not work:
`Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'visits.\`shows\`['city']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''city'' is of string type.;`

Comment: otherwise you can use explode as well. I edited the answer